# How to get value of particular clicked option of Multiselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown like this

```
<select id='companyList' class='js-select-Multiple' multiple = "true">
<option value='1'>ABC</option>
<option value='2'>PQR</option>
<option value='3'>XYZ</option>
</select>
```

I want to give an alert when a user clicks on any company
e.g. if user clicked XYZ, an alert will popup that 'this company is not available' like this

I tried:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#companyList', function (e)
    {
        alert(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
    });
```

but it doesn't give correct value

```
<script>
        $('#companyList').multiselect({
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: '300',
            buttonWidth: '235',
            numberDisplayed: 2,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select One or More',
        });     
</script>
```

Comment: You're using `#companyList`, but your select id is `#companies`

Comment: @Roberrrt: Works well after fixing the selector. Closing question.

Comment: see the edit   .  .@Roberrrt

Answer (score 0):

You have put your id wrongly.  you used `companyList` but actually the id is `company`.

```js
$('#companyList').multiselect({
            selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: '300',
            buttonWidth: '235',
            numberDisplayed: 2,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select One or More',
            onChange: function(element, checked) {
              console.log($(element).text());
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<select id='companyList' class='js-select-Multiple' multiple = "true">
<option value='1'>ABC</option>
<option value='2'>PQR</option>
<option value='3'>XYZ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, it's better to close a question that contains a simple typographical error than post an answer which will keep the question alive and ultimately clutter the website.

Comment: @Roberrrt at first i didn't notice that typographical error. I posted the answer with on change. then I saw that mistake

Comment: :) Cool, have a nice day!

Comment: but after clicking second option i want just value of second option.i.e.single value rather than comma seperated value @SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: still not working for me @SyedMohamedAladeen
may be because of multiselect

Comment: have you changed your id? the exact code is working in my above snippet

Comment: even your same code is not working on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide @SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: still not working ..i dont know how its working here and not anywhere? @SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: here I added jquery,bootsrtap and multiselect scripts. have you added those?